# Xamarin Forms fails to create an instance of DI container

Tags: android, xamarin, dependency-injection, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Using Visual Studio 2017.

Created the default Xamarin Forms project (.net standard 2.0 + android). No changes in project configuration, Debug mode.

`Compile -> Build -> Success` (simple page with a standard text).

Added `Unity/Autofac` and created an instance of the container in `App`.

In Unity:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Similar in AutoFac

p.s. tried the approach to skip linking assembly `System.Core`

**upd.1**

This is absolutely standard solution with the only 1 line of code:

```
public App ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var c = new UnityContainer(); //this is the line for Unity
        MainPage = new App2.MainPage();
    }
```

The scenario with Autofac is similar. But it fails on `RegisterType` with exception `Target of Add is null (NullReferenceException)`

**upd.2**

1. This fails both in Release and Debug mode
2. This does not fail in simulator!
3. This fails during any kind of execution on phone directly (inculding  Xamarin Live)

Comment: This is `NullPointException`, can you show your codes?

Comment: This is exactly `NullReferenceException` according to logs

Comment: You DI container doesn't *do* anything. It is not some magic black box, you need to wire up your application in a [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

Comment: This is not my application. This is an example of minimum app, which fails, and does not matter where it will be instantiated. But your comment is very reasonable. Eventually it heppend that devs of Xamarin Live did some reap magic, so android main activity is not invoked there, and App default ctor is the entry point...